# Point cloud object recognition with FPFH + svmlight

Tags: svm, point-cloud-library, object-recognition, feature-descriptor

I am doing a project for stair recognition which combines point cloud library(PCL) and svmlight. 
Now I am able to segment the point cloud, clustering and extract feature using fast point feature histogram([FPFH](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/fpfh_estimation.php)).

The problem is: How can I transform FPFH results(many FPFHSignature33 which is a feature cloud contents 33 histogram for each point) to a feature vector which can be as the input for svmlight?

I know I need to label "+1" or "-1" for pos or neg sample, but how about the feature vector or value for each data? 
I'm totally confused.

Any suggestion or hint is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to classify each feature point, a cluster of feature points, a whole image, etc.?

Comment: I have already clustered the point cloud and got the feature results for each PCD file. I guess I should classify the PCD file by these feature vector. To be clarify, how can I simplify FPFHSignature33 to a format that can be used for generating training file in SVM? thx

Comment: FPFHSignature33 is just a set of numbers (33 of them if I recall correctly - that is a 33 dimensional vector). It can be used directly as input to the SVM. If, however, you have extracted several FPFHSignature33 features and you need to classify the set of features the problem becomes more complex.

Comment: If there are a fixed number of feature points you can concatenate them according to some canonical order (e.g. by looking at the relative geometry of the points) (if you don't do this then you can imagine that you are expecting your classifier to generalise over rotations by itself), and then this does not solve the problem that there may not be a fixed number of features. Perhaps a good initial step is simply to average the feature histograms, but you will lose some information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Let's say I got a several point cloud file. After extracting the keypoint, each file have "different amount of points". And each point has a 33-dimensional vector which is FPFHSignature33.

Comment: I tried to summarise these results into one value for each point. Unfortunately, to average the feature histogram didn't work. I guess it's because of the method inside FPFH which will all result in the same value!
Have any idea for other method?

Comment: One question: Why are you working with FPFH and not with a global one like VFH? If you are stuck using FPFH why don't you set the radius of the feature point so that it encompasses the whole object and you get just one histogram? If you do this, of course there are better global representations like VFH. CVFH is another alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am just a newbie in computer vision's world. VFH seems to be a better feature descriptor for my situation. I will give it a try. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a global feature descriptor like [VFH](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_estimation.php) or [CVFH](http://pointclouds.org/news/2011/08/04/cvfh/). Here are some useful resources:

- [3D Descriptors for Object and Category Recognition: a Comparative Evaluation](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~lfbaa/pubs/iros2012.pdf).
- [Tutorial: Point Cloud Library: Three-Dimensional Object Recognition and 6 DOF Pose Estimation](http://robotics.usc.edu/~potthast/06299166.pdf).